# Using blender as a python module

Tags: python

How can I import Blender modules into any external Python IDE and use its features from the IDE itself?

I found the tutorial ["BlenderAsPyModule"](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) but I am unable to follow it… specifically I could't find any such directory as `"bin\bpy.pyd"`, as is specified in the link (under the section named 'Windows').

I am using Visual C++ 2008 express SP1 (whose download link is given in the above linked page), and `cmake` on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine.

Here is the **output log of generating build files using `cmake` with Visual Studio 9 2008**  :-

```
Blender Skipping: (bf_collada;bf_intern_ctr;extern_redcode)
Configuring done
Generating done
```

and here is the **output log of compiling (release build) the mvs solution file** (named *'blender'*) **:-**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: buildinfo, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Generating (some_path)/blendersvn/blender/source/creator/buildinfo.h
1>-- Found Subversion: (some_path)/svn/bin/svn.exe (found version "1.8.0") 
1>Build log was saved at "file://(some_path)\blendersvn\cmake-build\source\creator\buildinfo.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>buildinfo - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
2>------ Build started: Project: blender, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>Compiling...
2>buildinfo.c
2>Linking...
2>   Creating library (some_path)\blendersvn\cmake-build\lib\Release\bpy.lib and object (some_path)\blendersvn\cmake-build\lib\Release\bpy.exp
2>Embedding manifest...
2>Build log was saved at "file://(some_path)\blendersvn\cmake-build\source\creator\blender.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm"
2>blender - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 121 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It appears that there are no errors in these two steps. Is that correct?

Also, I copied `bpy.pyd` that lies inside `bin\Release\`  (instead of inside `bin\` as mentioned in the link) into `\python27\Lib\site-packages\`, but there are no `.dll` files in the `bin\Release\` directory to copy.

And then (just to add) here is the `ImportError`:

```
>>> import bpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import bpy
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Am I missing any part of the process or doing it wrong?

Comment: How did the build go? That file should exist if you set the `WITH_PYTHON_MODULE` flag to `ON`.

Comment: Your need to give more info - msvc or mingw? what versions? 64/32 bit?, what windows version. I maintain blender-as-a-python-module, but I mostly use Linux so rely on others letting me know if other OS's need fixing.

Comment: @CharlesL the build went fine supposedly....also there is only 1 folder inside `bin/` ,named `debug` , that contains `blender.exe`...however when I click on the blender executable, it throws the follwing `system error : the program cant start because python33_d.dll is missing....`

Comment: @ideasman42 I have updated my question with those details....also it would have been easier and helpful for beginners if there was some step by step screencast showing how to do this thing...:)

Comment: @apratim, this feature is not meant for beginners, its experimental for devs who are already building blender and may even be removed at some point (though at the moment I see no reason to do so). Screencasts can be nice but can't be maintained when there are changes to the build process. Developers should be able to follow text instructions if there well written.

Comment: @ideasman42 Ok...but where do you see the problem is in this case where there is no such directory `bin\bpy.pyd`.....also does it work with python 2.7? Or 3.3 is essentially required?

Comment: @apratimankur, added a **Troubleshooting** section to the wiki page.

Comment: @ideasman42 have updated my question with more details...see if I could be helped...and thank you for taking time to add the Troubleshooting section...

Comment: @apratimankur, I rather not put version numbers in docs since we do update python versions. But added this note ---
(if Blender us using Python3.3 then there is NO WAY to use another version - 2.7/3.2/3.4 will all fail).

Comment: @ideasman42 ok...so is it just the python version that is causing the problem? like the absence of `*.dll`s in `bin/release/`? and which blender version would support python 2.7?

Comment: Maybe, I cant say, I got this working once on a Windows-VM without doing anything special, but the wrong python version will fail for sure.
---
Blender2.49 was the last stable version of blender to support python 2.x series.

Comment: Voting to close this question, its less a question and more a request for support on building a specific configuration of Blender.

Comment: @ideasman42 the question shouldn't have been closed, I'm a programmer and need to use blender module, having problems with building, wished this quesiton had an answer

Comment: This site is about using Blender, problems building Blender are out of scope. Note that MSVC2008 is no longer supported. (Only MSVC2013)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11102681/321973